# Sitecore JSS does not deliver dictionary entries from pathes specified in config files

Tags: jss, dictionary

Sitecore JSS does not deliver dictionary entries from pathes specified in config files. https://xxx.local/sitecore/api/jss/dictionary/xxx/en?sc_apikey={6B8DB342-F35D-481F-8C16-87B7319B6F6E} returns dictionary entries from system/dictionary, but in config files pointed

```
<app name="xxx"
                     sitecorePath="/sitecore/content/xxx local/xxx"
                     useLanguageSpecificLayout="true"
                     graphQLEndpoint="/api/WineShop"
                     importDatabase="web"
                     inherits="defaults"

        />
```

and there is folder xxx Dictionary which has dictionary entries which are not delivered.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't updated the sample project given by JSS then the dictionary service URL will be generated something like below from the jss app.

```
const dictionaryServicePath = `${config.sitecoreApiHost}/sitecore/api/jss/dictionary/${config.jssAppName}/{{lng}}?sc_apikey=${config.sitecoreApiKey}`;
```

But in your case looks like you tried with the direct URL and that returns entries from system/dictionary. So check your include folder and verify whether you have the updated/proper jss app config .\Website\App_Config\Include\JSS-APP-Name.config.

Because you get error/improper results when you access the direct URLs like https://xxx.local/sitecore/api/jss/dictionary/xxx/en?sc_apikey={6B8DB342-F35D-481F-8C16-87B7319B6F6E} so the issue will be with the jss-app config files which you deployed in your Sitecore instance or the Sitecore content tree [which may not have the proper content tree/structure]

Actually the jss document is really helpful  https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/fundamentals/services/dictionary-service

Answer (score 1):

The Sitecore JSS comes with a set of default configurations located in

```
App_Config\Sitecore\JavaScriptServices\Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Apps.config
```

Since your  configuration setting does not include the dictionary path, it will use the following default settings found in Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Apps.config.

```
dictionaryPath="$sitecorePath/$name Dictionary"
dictionaryDomain="$name Dictionary"
```

Now, if Sitecore is unable to find your dictionary files based on the "dictionaryPath" in the configuration, it will fallback to use "/sitecore/system/dictionary", which is the behavior that you are observing.

To solve your problem, I am guessing it could not find your dictionary path. Do check if it is in the correct path, or patch it in your config to desired path.

```
<App name="xxx" 
    dictionaryPath="Enter your sitecore dictionary path ..."
    dictionaryDomain="Enter your sitecore dictionary domain ..."
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

A shot in the dark here, but have you tried deleting `dictionary.dat` file from your Sitecore installation `/temp` folder? That should regenerate the dictionary file with the latest dictionary items (as long those are published).